# MySQL: Get two rows as one

Tags: mysql, sql

users table:

```
id  |   win  |   lose
0   |   1    |   2
1   |   2    |   8
```

games table:

```
id  |  user1  |  user2  |  data
0   |  0      |  1      |  'some text'
```

The DB is for a simple multiplayer game. I need a query to get user2, data, **and win-lose data for both users**. Is this possible in MySQL at all? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to `JOIN` the table `users` two times like this:

```
SELECT
  u1.win  AS win1,
  u1.lose AS lose1,
  u2.win  AS win2,
  u2.lose AS lose2,
  ...
FROM games g
INNER JOIN users u1 ON g.user1 = u1.id
INNER JOIN users u2 ON g.user2 = u2.id
```

Comment: thanks, don'really know whats going on, but it's working so... thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can join the `users` table twice:

```
SELECT
    games.user2 AS user2_id
    games.data AS games_data
    user1.win AS user1_win,
    user1.lose AS user1_lose,
    user2.win AS user2_win,
    user2.lose AS user2_lose
FROM games
JOIN users AS user1 ON user1.id = games.user1
JOIN users AS user2 ON user2.id = games.user2
WHERE games.id = ...
```

Comment: Ok, I should have refreshed more often, this is the same answer as Mahmoud Gamal's

Comment: nevertheless I appreciate it!

Comment: Thanks, I polished it a bit by capitalizing all the 'AS' keywords :-)